# Readonly Field used as a normal field

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I was checking an online tutorial video and I noticed this code modifying a readonly field without constructor and it was working fine. How & Why it works?

```
  public class Journal
  {
    private readonly List<string> entries = new List<string>();

    private static int count = 0;

    public int AddEntry(string text)
    {
      entries.Add($"{++count}: {text}");
      return count; // memento pattern!
    }

    public void RemoveEntry(int index)
    {
      entries.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, entries);
    }
  }

  public class Demo
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var j = new Journal();
      j.AddEntry("I cried today.");
      j.AddEntry("I ate a mango.");
      WriteLine(j);
    }
  }
```

output:

> 1. I cried today.
> 2. I ate a mango.

Comment: There's no code that modifies the *field*

Comment: `entries` is `readonly`; you can't assign a new `List<string>` to it after the class is constructed. `List<string>` is a reference type, so  you can mutate its properties and use its methods to mutate it, etc.

Comment: @Loocid you *can't* modify a readonly object, eg a `record` or a `readonly struct`. `List` isn't a readonly object. It's the field that's readonly

Comment: I've added a second duplicate which shows how you can prevent a list from being modified. Again, this only stops you mutating the list itself. If the list items are reference types, then you can mutate them to your heart's content.

Answer (score 4):

What is really happening here is that a method called on the `entries` readonly field and it Does NOT change the reference of the `entries` field.

Changing the reference of the readonly field is a compile error, but calling a method on the readonly (whatever it does internally) has no problem at all

Try the following statement

```
entries = new List<string>();
```

and you will see the error